# Использование наследования в unity3d

Tags: наследование, c#, unity3d

Ребята, в связи с ситуацией пришлось познакомится с наследованием по быстрому, принцип понял, но на деле беда, когда я дописал 1 класс, все было в норме, когда начал писать 2 класс, и брать переменные из 1. Он их попросту не видит, но это еще что, когда я сохраняю скрипт, пытаюсь запустить сцену, юнити ругается, дезскать ты забыл исправить ошибки, но консоль молчит, так же молчит и monodevelop.

Мне сказали что тут проблемы с наследованием, но где?
**Очень нужна ваша помощь, вся надежда на вас.**
Код вроде простой, понятный, если что пишите, обозначу что и как работает.
Что нужно исправить? Как вернуть сообщения консоли?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

    class BaseWeapon
    {
        public int weapon_damage, ammo_amount, reload_time;
        public bool weapon_active=false;
        public GameObject pistolprefab;
        public GameObject autorifleprefab;
        public GameObject currect_weapon;
        public GameObject previos_weapon;
        public BaseWeapon pistol = new BaseWeapon(10, 7, 2);
        public BaseWeapon autorifle = new BaseWeapon(20, 30, 5);

        public BaseWeapon(int wd, int aa, int rt)
        {
            weapon_damage = wd;
            ammo_amount = aa;
            reload_time = rt;
        }

        public void weapon_on_off()
        {
            if (weapon_active=true)
            {
                currect_weapon.SetActive(true);
                previos_weapon.SetActive(false);
            }

        }
    }

class ManagerWeapon 
{
    public void change_weapon()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("1"))
        {
            currect_weapon=pistol;
            previos_weapon=autorifle;
                weapon_active=true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("2"))
        {
            currect_weapon=autorifle;
            previos_weapon=pistol;
            weapon_active=true;
        }
    }
}
    void Start()
    {
        currect_weapon=pistol;
        previos_weapon=autorifle;
        weapon_active=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: а где у вас наследование (кроме **Weapon : MonoBehaviour**)? У вас какая-то адская каша из вложенных классов. Вероятно, вам имеет смысл изучить самые основы языка и ООП

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я помню C# допускает в одном файле только один класс. И класс Weapon как я понял у Вас бесполезен. У вас должна получится следующая структура.

Файл BaseWeapon.cpp:

```
public class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour {
...
}
```

Файл ManagerWeapon.cpp:

```
public class ManagerWeapon : BaseWeapon{
...
}
```

Т.е. BaseWeapon наследует MonoBehaviour, а ManagerWeapon наследует BaseWeapon ну и MonoBehaviour тоже так как его наследует BaseWeapon :)

Comment: В C# разрешено определение нескольких классов в одном файле. Файлы исходного кода обычно имеют расширение `.cs`.

Answer (score 3):

Коллега у вас нет наследования здесь. Как говорил мой консультант: "Одновременно варим борщ и пельмени в одной кастрюли ". Переменные

```
public GameObject pistolprefab;
public GameObject autorifleprefab;
public GameObject currect_weapon;
public GameObject previos_weapon;
public BaseWeapon pistol = new BaseWeapon(10, 7, 2);
public BaseWeapon autorifle = new BaseWeapon(20, 30, 5);
```

следует переместить в тело `WeaponManager`. Поскольку в его задачу, если я правильно понял входит создание арсенала оружия и переключения между разными видами. Само оружие знать о том какие виды его существуют не должно, и совсем не логично что оно само себя создает. Так что я бы унаследовал `WeaponManager` от `MonoBehaviour` и в него перенес `Start` и `weapon_on_off` 
Возможно вы хотели сделать базовый класс оружия `BaseWeapon`, а от него уже наследовать прочее оружие вроде автомата и пистолета.

```
public class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour {
public int weapon_damage, ammo_amount, reload_time;
public bool weapon_active=false;
public BaseWeapon(int wd, int aa, int rt)
    {
        weapon_damage = wd;
        ammo_amount = aa;
        reload_time = rt;
    }
...
}
```

`MonoBehaviour` указываем если хотите оружие вешать как компонент на объекты. Если для вас это хранилище данных то можно и не наследоваться от `MonoBehaviour`. А уже ваши классы наследники будут выглядеть так:

Пистолет:

```
public class Pistole: BaseWeapon {    
...
}
```

Винтовка:

```
public class Riffle: BaseWeapon {    
...
}
```

В каждом из потомков `Pistole` и `Riffle` будет доступна любая public переменная заданная в родительском классе.
Федор мой вам совет, разделяйте классы по разным одноименным файлам, это поможет вам в дальнейшем не путаться когда нужно будет найти требуемый класс.